# Place % in file path

Tags: graphics, external-files

How can I reference a file path that contains a %? Using the standard escape (\%) does not seem to work. Unfortunately, changing the directory name is not an option. Example:

```
      \includegraphics{Q:/2014 - 2015/Change (%)/Graphic Name.png}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try with

```
\usepackage{grffile}
\begingroup\catcode`\%=12
\def\x{\def\strangepath{Q:/2014 - 2015/Change (%)}}
\expandafter\endgroup\x
```

in your document preamble and

```
\includegraphics{\strangepath/Graphic Name.png}
```

in the document.

Answer (score 6):

Filenames with spaces and percent :(

You could `\@percentchar` instead of `%` if `@` is a letter at that point, or locally put `` \catcode`\%=12 `` before the `\includegraphics`, to make `%` a normal character. You need `"` .. `"` around the filename as well because of the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

`\detokenize{}` around the filename worked for me.

Example:
`\includegraphics{\detokenize{file name including \% sign.png}}`.

Comment: `\detokenize` with `\%` will (under normal circumstances) produce `\%` and not `%`

Comment: Hm, it worked for me, but maybe it really produced `\%` and LaTeX still finds the correct graphic?

Comment: Sorry, I should have checked.  What I said in my first comment is true, but when LaTeX is parsing a filename it is _not_ under those normal circumstances I mentioned:  when scanning a file name LaTeX sets `\escapechar=-1`, so `\detokenize{\%}` produces `%`.  Your solution indeed works! (but since LaTeX from 2019 or so).  P.S.: `\includegraphics{file \string\% name.png}` also works